# Using assign and lambda to combine year and month columns into 1 date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file with the following columns that I read into a pandas dataframe:

```
Year    Month   Day   Hour
2012    1       1     0
2012    1       1     1
2012    1       1     2
2012    1       1     3`
```

I'm trying to combine these 3 columns into a datetime column using the following code:

```
df1 = df.assign(Dt = lambda row: datetime.datetime(row['Year'].astype(int), row['Month'].astype(int)...))
```

This code gives the following error: 
   `Type Error: Cannot convert the series to (Type 'int')`

I know I can just combine these columns into a string and use `strptime` to convert to `datetime`. HoweverI i want to try to understand what i'm doing wrong with assign and lambda here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your columns are appropriately named to use `pd.to_datetime` directly on the `df`

```
df.assign(Dt=pd.to_datetime(df))

   Year  Month  Day  Hour                  Dt
0  2012      1    1     0 2012-01-01 00:00:00
1  2012      1    1     1 2012-01-01 01:00:00
2  2012      1    1     2 2012-01-01 02:00:00
3  2012      1    1     3 2012-01-01 03:00:00
```

which simplifies to:

```
df.assign(Dt=pd.to_datetime)
```

---

[From the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

[image]

The passed callable is not called once per row as you think.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I guess i got confused by the the df.assign(ln_A = lambda x: np.log(x.A)) example in the doc. So what is the callable and how is it called in df.assign?